# Lotus Notes: NotesSQL on Windows 2008 - ODBC Problem

Tags: .net, database, odbc, windows-server-2008, lotus-notes

I want to use the **NotesSQL ODBC driver** to access Lotus Notes **NSF files**. Because of some reasons I must do this on a **Windows Server 2008**. Unfortunately I cannot configure the ODBC datasource on this OS! On XP it works fine!

Error message:

[image]

Has anybody a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

NotesSQL is 32-bit only. If you are using it on an 64-bit operating system, you must use

SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

using command line to configure system DSNs. For more information check this:

http://www.keysolutions.com/NotesFAQ/cannotessql.html

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that your not using the correct Notes ODBC driver for the OS, I hope you can get a driver for Windows Server 2008 but if you can't find one via google see what you can find at www.lotus.com (IBM but Lotus is a whole area of the site), you can also email them and they may be able to help.